# Django context processor gets AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django

instead of User.

```
def myview(request):   
    return render_to_response('tmpl.html', {'user': User.objects.get(id=1})
```

works fine and passes User to template.
But

```
def myview(request):   
    return render_to_response('tmpl.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

with a context processor

```
def user(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    return {'user': User.objects.get(id=1)}
```

passes AnonymousUser, so I can't get the variables I need :(
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your context processor is enabled in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py?

More to the point, does it come before or after the built-in `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`? If it's before, it will be overridden by that processor, which will redefine `user` as the actual logged-in user, or AnonymousUser if none.

Comment: Solved. Just moved my context processor to the **end** of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Thanks